# Order in a First Order Logic Statement with Quantifiers?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, quantifiers

I'm struggling to figure out the difference between these two statements:

∀a ∈ A : ∃b ∈ B so that something holds,
and 
∃b ∈ B : ∀a ∈ A so that something holds.

We're asked to give an example but I'm looking to clarify the distinction. Thanks all!

Comment: The first one means that for all $a \in A$ there exists a $b \in B$ so that something holds. So for any element in $A$ we can assign an element in $B$. For example, for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists a $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a-b=1$ (namely the element $a - 1$). The second one means that there exists a $b \in B$ such that for all $a \in A$ something holds. So there exists some element in $B$ so that for any element in $A$ something holds. For example, there exists a $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $ab=0$. This $b$ would be the number $0$.

Comment: Compare $\forall n \exists m (n < m)$ with $\exists m \forall n (n < m)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall a\in A:\exists b\in B$ is also expressed as $\forall a~\exists b~(a\in A\to b\in B)$.

This is satisfied when something is in $B$ *or* nothing is in $A$.

---

$\exists b\in B:\forall a\in A$ is also expressed as $\exists b~\forall a~(b\in B\wedge a\in A)$.

This is satisfied when something is in $B$ *and* everything is in $A$.